# MVC Contrib grid failing on .OrderBy() with NHibernate Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mvccontrib-grid

I have been following [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx) nice walkthrough for creating a grid using MVC contrib.

My version is however using NHibernate, not linq to entities.

The code is working fine up to the point of sorting.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string clientName, int? countryId, GridSortOptions gridSortOptions, int? page)
    {
        var clientList = from c in this.ClientRepository.Query
                         select new ListedClientViewModel(c);

        //Set default sort column
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gridSortOptions.Column))
            gridSortOptions.Column = "ClientName";

        // Filter on clientName
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientName))
            clientList = clientList.Where(c => c.ClientName.StartsWith(clientName));

        // Filter on country
        if (countryId.HasValue)
            clientList = clientList.Where(c => c.CountryId == countryId);

        // Order and page the clients
        var clientPageList = clientList
            //Sorting causes error.
            //.OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction)
            .AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);

        var clientListContainer = new ClientListContainerViewModel
        {
            ClientPageList = clientPageList,
            GridSortOptions = gridSortOptions
        };

        return View(clientListContainer);
    }
```

If i uncomment the line `.OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction)`it will fail when it hits the view with an `System.NotSupportedException {"NewExpression"}`

Any ideas how i can solve this issue?

Many thanks, Kohan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it... Simply had to cast the view model later on after the filtering and ordering had been applied.

```
  var clientList = this.ClientRepository.Query;

  ...
  ...

  // Order and page the clients
  var clientPageList = clientList
       //Sorting no longer causes error.
       .OrderBy(gridSortOptions.Column, gridSortOptions.Direction)
       .Select(c => new ListedClientViewModel(c))
       .AsPagination(page ?? 1, 10);
```